# How to pass object with history.push in react-router v5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How do I play a sound on the /start-sound and stop the sound on the /stop-sound?

**/start-sound**

```
const history = useHistory();

const startSound = () => {
  const sound = new Audio("test.mp3");
  sound.play();
  history.push("/stop-sound", [sound]);
}
```

**/stop-sound**

```
const stopSound = () => {
  sound.pause();
  sound.currentTime = 0;
}
```

This code will display an error in the browser.

> DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': An object could not be cloned.

---

```
history.push("/stop-sound", [sound]);
```

This style will follow the React Router documentation.

[React Router | history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history)

And I don't know how to use sound object with /stop-sound.

---

### Another example

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-panini-b7n6s?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

**/pass-text**

```
const PassTextPage = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const passText= () => {
    history.push({
      pathname: "/view-text",
      state: { name: "Hello" }
    });
  };

  return <button onClick={passText}>pass</button>;
};
```

**/view-text**

```
const ViewTextPage = () => {
  const text = props.location.state.name; // 'props' is not defined.

  const viewText = () => {
    console.log(text);
  };

  return <button onClick={viewText}>view</button>;
};
```

**App.jsx**

```
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/pass-text">
      <PassTextPage />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/view-text">
      <ViewTextPage />
    </Route>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: include props in const ViewTextPage = (props)

Comment: I got the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined".

Comment: Post the parent component of viewTextPage component

Comment: Added parent components for two components.

Comment: Add the code in root component.  import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router } from "react-router";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>,document.getElementById('root') 
);

Comment: I got the error "The above error occurred in the <ViewTextPage> component...".

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-panini-b7n6s?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark   Created a demo, so please check it if you like.

Comment: Change your parent component something like this <Route exact path="/view-text" component={ViewTextPage} />

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-albattani-kbguh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark  I passed the string object but could not pass the Audio object. Is there a way to pass Audio objects?

Answer (score 7):

The way you can pass property to navigated component

```
history.push({
pathname: '/stop-sound',
  state: { name: 'Hello'}
});
```

access like this in navigated component.

if its stateless component

```
let location = useLocation();

location.state.name
```

if class based component

```
 this.props.location.state.name
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.   When writing "props.location.state.name" in stop-sound.jsx, the error "'prop' is not defined." was displayed.  Is there anything else you are missing?  I added the detailed code to the question, so please answer again if you like.  Sorry for the rudimentary question.